# How to remove last tab from line (while loop)

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to remove just the last tab character from a 1xN vector. The function calculates the mean of a matrix and prints the 1 line result.

I am not able to use awk, sed, tcl, bc, perl, & the python languages

I've tried an if statement and while loop using the following code.

```
if [[ line[-1] ]]
```

My function is below.

```
mean() {
    input="${1:-/dev/stdin}"              #input variable equal to file or text from stdin

    transpose $input > tempmeanfile       #call transpose function and place results in temp file

    while read -a line                    #while loop reads the entire file
    do 
        count=0                           #count variable holds the rows count
        sum=0                             #sum variable holds the tallied sum 
        mean=0
        for i in "${line[@]}"             #for loop loops through the rows 
        do
            ((sum += $i))                 #each number in the row is summed, left with one column
            ((count++))                   #rows are incremented                
        done
        ((mean = sum/count))              #mean is set equal to the sum divided by the number of rows
        printf "$mean\t"                    #print mean values 
    done < tempmeanfile                   #while temp file has not been read
    printf "\n"                           #print new line
}
```

Sample input
[1\t2\t3\n4\t5\t6]

after transpose function is called
[1\t4\n2\t5\n3\t6]

Sample output
2\t5\t9\t

Comment: is it just that your `count` value is one to many? Then just `((count --))` before you use it for your calculation? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use regex each line string:

```sh
for i in `expr "${line[@]}" : 's/^    *$//'`
```